# Diagrammer: how to add labels to mermaid connectors

Tags: r, diagrammer

I am trying R DiagrammeR library, and can noT add a label for the connectors between boxes...
My code (which works fine) is:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("
graph TD
        A[node 1]-->B[node 2]
        A-->C[node 3]
        C-->E[another node]
        B-->D[node 4]
        ")
```

Using the function grViz of the same library, labels could be added like:

```
 A[label:'This is the NO path"]
```

but this way gives error in mermaid function...
I tried:

```
 A[node 1]-->B[node 2][label="test"]
 A[node 1]-->B[node 2, label="test"]
```

and many others with no success.

I want something similar to this diagramm with the 'YES' added in a connection
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `|Yes|` between `A-->` and `C[node 3]`.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("
graph TD
        A[node 1]--> B[node 2]
        A-->|Yes| C[node 3]
        C-->E[another node]
        B-->D[node 4]
        ")
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the line between node 1 and node 3 birectional?